# get following nested array webservice in php using the mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

```
"data":{  
   "2":{  
      "sub_category_id":"1",
      "product":[  
         {  
            "sub_category_id":"1",
            "product_id":"1",
            "product_name":"American"
         },
         {  
            "sub_category_id":"1",
            "product_id":"34",
            "product_name":"Ausi Product"
         }
      ]
   },
   "3":{  
      "sub_category_id":"2",
      "product":{  
         "2":{  
            "sub_category_id":"2",
            "product_id":"2",
            "product_name":"Canadian"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What i excepted result:

```
"data":[  
   "2":{  
      "sub_category_id":"1",
      "product":[  
         {  
            "sub_category_id":"1",
            "product_id":"1",
            "product_name":"American"
         },
         {  
            "sub_category_id":"1",
            "product_id":"34",
            "product_name":"Ausi Product"
         }
      ]
   },
   "3":{  
      "sub_category_id":"2",
      "product":[  
         "2":{  
            "sub_category_id":"2",
            "product_id":"2",
            "product_name":"Canadian"
         }
      ]
   ]
```

i.e. i wantel [] after data and product.

Comment: a little bit of your code in the post would go a long way to avoid all the `clarification` comments.  Read **[this useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** about a Minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: Do you want to create JSON? Both structures are invalid JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You can instruct the PHP [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to parse objects into associative arrays.

```
$parsedJSON = json_decode($jsonString, /* $assoc = */ true)
```

Comment: motherhood and apple pie. Not related to this unclear (at best) question.

Comment: also if you had read the comments you also would have known that both structures are invalid JSON so json_decode won't be a option.